# Getting error using credentials to get accountid:getcalleridentity in aws -terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I created an aws account and an IAM user for terraform -administrator access and got my credentials.
I am now trying to create an EC2 instance in AWS using terraform.I am running the below terraform script from git bash.

```
provider "aws"{
access_key = "Axxxxxxxxx"
secret_key = "Lxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
region="us-east-1"
}
resource "aws_instance" "example"{
ami="ami-0323c3dd2da7fb37d"
instance_type="t2.micro"
}
```

When i give terraform plan,I am getting the following error:

```
Error: error using credentials to get account ID: error calling sts:GetCallerIdentity: SignatureDoesNotMatch: Signature not yet current: 20200518T060344Z is still later than 20200518T041739Z (20200518T040239Z + 15 min.)
        status code: 403, request id: 7d93e368-bf05-4110-9876-1bf6064dd255

  on instance.tf line 1, in provider "aws":
   1: provider "aws"{
```

I am new to AWS as well as terraform.Can you please let me know why this error appears?I tried updating the git bash.If I am missing out something,please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your system clock may be miss-configured.

From [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=103764#) AWS forum thread:

> API services verify timestamps to be within **5 minutes** of actual time. If the system clock is off by **more than 5 minutes, then the API requests will fail**.

Comment: Suddenly the clock on my WSL Ubuntu-18.04 changed for some reason. Doing `wsl --shutdown` rebooted the WSL instances and the date gets corrected.